Color highlighting in lstlistings
I use the lstlistings package for SQL code and I when I add additional keywords they do not appear in color. A minimal working example is as follows
\documentclass[A4paper]{article}

% Use utf8 input encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Use Latin Modern high-quality fonts
\usepackage{lmodern}

% For colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

% To have the \textquotesingle in listings
\usepackage{textcomp}
% For listings
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=SQL, columns=fullflexible, showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,% Enable UTF8 accentuated characters
  upquote=true,% Straight quotes in code
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},% We cannot use '*' to make keywords appear in upper case
  commentstyle=\color{purple},%
  alsoletter={&},
  % literate={-}{-}1, % Do not replace hyphen by minus symbol
  % alsodigit={-},
  % alsoletter={-},
  morecomment=[l][commentstyle]{--},%
  morecomment=[s][commentstyle]{/*}{*/},%
  morekeywords={ALWAYS,BIGINT,BOOLEAN,COPY,COSTS,EPOCH,EXPLAIN,
    FILTER,FOR,FUNCTION,GENERATED,GROUPING,HASH,IF,IS,LATERAL,
    LEAD,LIST,MODE,MODULUS,OF,OFF,ON,OVER,PARALLEL,PARTITION,
    PRECEDING,RANGE,RANK,REFERENCES,REMAINDER,SETS,SYSTEM,
    TABLESAMPLE,TEXT,TIMESTAMPTZ,TO,UNBOUNDED,UNSAFE,WITH,
    WITHIN,WITHOUT},
  deletekeywords={lower,of}}
% To disable the replacement of hyphen with minus sign
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
  \lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{\lst@ttfamily{*{}}{*}}
  \lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-}}
  \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is a test for color highlighting using the lstlistings package. 
The added keywords are given next.

\begin{lstlisting}[language=sql]
  morekeywords={ALWAYS,BIGINT,BOOLEAN,COPY,COSTS,EPOCH,EXPLAIN,
    FILTER,FOR,FUNCTION,GENERATED,GROUPING,HASH,IF,IS,LATERAL,
    LEAD,LIST,MODE,MODULUS,OF,OFF,ON,OVER,PARALLEL,PARTITION,
    PRECEDING,RANGE,RANK,REFERENCES,REMAINDER,SETS,SYSTEM,
    TABLESAMPLE,TEXT,TIMESTAMPTZ,TO,UNBOUNDED,UNSAFE,WITH,
    WITHIN,WITHOUT},
\end{lstlisting}
The following examples shows that the added keywords do not apper in color.
\begin{lstlisting}[language=sql]
SELECT TripId, PointId AS P1, T AS T1, Geom AS Geom1,
  LEAD(PointId, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY TripId ORDER BY PointId) AS P2,
  LEAD(T, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY TripId ORDER BY PointId) AS T2,
  LEAD(Geom, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY TripId ORDER BY PointId) AS Geom2
FROM GPSPoint;
ALTER TABLE FlighstInput
  ADD COLUMN EtTs timestamp,
  ADD COLUMN EtTstz timestamptz;
SELECT s.*, SUM(SalesAmount) OVER (ORDER BY SalesAmount DESC
  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumulSales
FROM SalesCountry s;
CREATE TABLE Trips_HashPart_1 PARTITION OF Trips_HashPart
  FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 3, REMAINDER 0);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

The output shows as follows


Welcome to TeX.SX and thank you for the shown minimal working example!

LaTeX is case-sensitive. Already your A4paper is wrong and results in:
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [A4paper].

because the option is a4paper not A4paper.
Your \lstset{language=SQL,…} already setup everything. So you don't need to setup the language again for every lstlisting. Removing the language=sql from the lstlisting environments:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}% Fixed!

% Use utf8 input encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Not needed for more than a decade!
% Use Latin Modern high-quality fonts
\usepackage{lmodern}

% For colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

% To have the \textquotesingle in listings
\usepackage{textcomp}% not needed any longer
% For listings
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=SQL, columns=fullflexible, showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,% Enable UTF8 accentuated characters
  upquote=true,% Straight quotes in code
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},% We cannot use '*' to make keywords appear in upper case
  commentstyle=\color{purple},%
  alsoletter={&},
  % literate={-}{-}1, % Do not replace hyphen by minus symbol
  % alsodigit={-},
  % alsoletter={-},
  morecomment=[l][commentstyle]{--},%
  morecomment=[s][commentstyle]{/*}{*/},%
  morekeywords={ALWAYS,BIGINT,BOOLEAN,COPY,COSTS,EPOCH,EXPLAIN,
    FILTER,FOR,FUNCTION,GENERATED,GROUPING,HASH,IF,IS,LATERAL,
    LEAD,LIST,MODE,MODULUS,OF,OFF,ON,OVER,PARALLEL,PARTITION,
    PRECEDING,RANGE,RANK,REFERENCES,REMAINDER,SETS,SYSTEM,
    TABLESAMPLE,TEXT,TIMESTAMPTZ,TO,UNBOUNDED,UNSAFE,WITH,
    WITHIN,WITHOUT},
  deletekeywords={lower,of}}
% To disable the replacement of hyphen with minus sign
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
  \lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{\lst@ttfamily{*{}}{*}}
  \lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-}}
  \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is a test for color highlighting using the lstlistings package. 
The added keywords are given next.

\begin{lstlisting}
  morekeywords={ALWAYS,BIGINT,BOOLEAN,COPY,COSTS,EPOCH,EXPLAIN,
    FILTER,FOR,FUNCTION,GENERATED,GROUPING,HASH,IF,IS,LATERAL,
    LEAD,LIST,MODE,MODULUS,OF,OFF,ON,OVER,PARALLEL,PARTITION,
    PRECEDING,RANGE,RANK,REFERENCES,REMAINDER,SETS,SYSTEM,
    TABLESAMPLE,TEXT,TIMESTAMPTZ,TO,UNBOUNDED,UNSAFE,WITH,
    WITHIN,WITHOUT},
\end{lstlisting}
The following examples shows that the added keywords do not apper in color.
\begin{lstlisting}
SELECT TripId, PointId AS P1, T AS T1, Geom AS Geom1,
  LEAD(PointId, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY TripId ORDER BY PointId) AS P2,
  LEAD(T, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY TripId ORDER BY PointId) AS T2,
  LEAD(Geom, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY TripId ORDER BY PointId) AS Geom2
FROM GPSPoint;
ALTER TABLE FlighstInput
  ADD COLUMN EtTs timestamp,
  ADD COLUMN EtTstz timestamptz;
SELECT s.*, SUM(SalesAmount) OVER (ORDER BY SalesAmount DESC
  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumulSales
FROM SalesCountry s;
CREATE TABLE Trips_HashPart_1 PARTITION OF Trips_HashPart
  FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 3, REMAINDER 0);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

results in:

If you instead use language=SQL again, the keywords would be reset again to the definition of that language. And because your morekeywords are not part of the language but of the setting done with \lstset they are no longer known as keywords. To avoid this you can, e.g., define your own language:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}% Fixed!

% Use utf8 input encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Not needed for more than a decade!
% Use Latin Modern high-quality fonts
\usepackage{lmodern}

% For colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

% To have the \textquotesingle in listings
\usepackage{textcomp}% not needed any longer
% For listings
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible, showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,% Enable UTF8 accentuated characters
  upquote=true,% Straight quotes in code
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},% We cannot use '*' to make keywords appear in upper case
  commentstyle=\color{purple},%
}
\lstdefinelanguage{mySQL}{%
  language=SQL,
  alsoletter={&},
  % literate={-}{-}1, % Do not replace hyphen by minus symbol
  % alsodigit={-},
  % alsoletter={-},
  morecomment=[l][commentstyle]{--},%
  morecomment=[s][commentstyle]{/*}{*/},%
  morekeywords={ALWAYS,BIGINT,BOOLEAN,COPY,COSTS,EPOCH,EXPLAIN,
    FILTER,FOR,FUNCTION,GENERATED,GROUPING,HASH,IF,IS,LATERAL,
    LEAD,LIST,MODE,MODULUS,OF,OFF,ON,OVER,PARALLEL,PARTITION,
    PRECEDING,RANGE,RANK,REFERENCES,REMAINDER,SETS,SYSTEM,
    TABLESAMPLE,TEXT,TIMESTAMPTZ,TO,UNBOUNDED,UNSAFE,WITH,
    WITHIN,WITHOUT},
  deletekeywords={lower,of}}
% To disable the replacement of hyphen with minus sign
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
  \lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{\lst@ttfamily{*{}}{*}}
  \lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-}}
  \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is a test for color highlighting using the lstlistings package. 
The added keywords are given next.

\begin{lstlisting}[language=mySQL]
  morekeywords={ALWAYS,BIGINT,BOOLEAN,COPY,COSTS,EPOCH,EXPLAIN,
    FILTER,FOR,FUNCTION,GENERATED,GROUPING,HASH,IF,IS,LATERAL,
    LEAD,LIST,MODE,MODULUS,OF,OFF,ON,OVER,PARALLEL,PARTITION,
    PRECEDING,RANGE,RANK,REFERENCES,REMAINDER,SETS,SYSTEM,
    TABLESAMPLE,TEXT,TIMESTAMPTZ,TO,UNBOUNDED,UNSAFE,WITH,
    WITHIN,WITHOUT},
\end{lstlisting}
The following examples shows that the added keywords do not apper in color.
\begin{lstlisting}[language=mySQL]
SELECT TripId, PointId AS P1, T AS T1, Geom AS Geom1,
  LEAD(PointId, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY TripId ORDER BY PointId) AS P2,
  LEAD(T, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY TripId ORDER BY PointId) AS T2,
  LEAD(Geom, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY TripId ORDER BY PointId) AS Geom2
FROM GPSPoint;
ALTER TABLE FlighstInput
  ADD COLUMN EtTs timestamp,
  ADD COLUMN EtTstz timestamptz;
SELECT s.*, SUM(SalesAmount) OVER (ORDER BY SalesAmount DESC
  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumulSales
FROM SalesCountry s;
CREATE TABLE Trips_HashPart_1 PARTITION OF Trips_HashPart
  FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 3, REMAINDER 0);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

Result as shown above.
Defining a new listings style or even a new listings environment would also be a suggestion. See the listings documentation for more information about these alternatives.
Just an additional note: \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} and \usepackage{textcomp} are not needed for a long time. See ltnews.pdf for more information about improvements and changes in LaTeX for the last three decades. Issue 31, February 2020 (LATEX release 2020-02-02) there instructs you about the relevant encoding changes.
